# Why this dictionary values are all the same?

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to write this dictionary comprehension and I don't know why all the dictionary values are the same.

The code is:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

dictionary = {key: value for key in range(0, len(ascii_uppercase)) for value in ascii_uppercase}
```

The result is:

```
{0: 'Z', 1: 'Z', 2: 'Z', 3: 'Z', 4: 'Z', 5: 'Z', 6: 'Z', 7: 'Z', 8: 'Z', 9: 'Z', 10: 'Z', 11: 'Z', 12: 'Z', 13: 'Z', 14: 'Z', 15: 'Z', 16: 'Z', 17: 'Z', 18: 'Z', 19: 'Z', 20: 'Z', 21: 'Z', 22: 'Z', 23: 'Z', 24: 'Z', 25: 'Z'}
```

Why it is only giving me the last character of the string as all the values?
How can I fix it?

Comment: It's basically running 26 times all the way through

Comment: When you have multiple `for x in` statements in a comprehension, they are _nested_, with the rightmost expression being the outermost loop.  On the final execution of the outer loop on `value`, it is equal to Z, and then the inner loop sets every key to that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert the dict comprehension into regular loops, you have this:

```
dictionary = {}
for key in range(0, len(ascii_uppercase)): # for every number in range 0-26
    for value in ascii_uppercase:          # for every letter in range a-z
        dictionary[key] = value            # d[num] = letter
```

The last letter for every number is `'z'` so your dictionary is updated with it at the end of inner loop for each number.

You can try:

```
di = {}
for i, letter in enumerate(ascii_uppercase):
    di[i] = letter
```

or

```
di = {i: letter for i, letter in enumerate(ascii_uppercase)}
```

or

```
di = dict(enumerate(ascii_uppercase))
```

Comment: first of all, I want to use comprehension not regular loops, and second, what if I want to some how relate two different lists and write a dictionary comprehension?

Comment: First of all, the loops are there to help you understand what *you* are actually doing and second, you will probably looking for `zip` but `enumerate` is much easier and more Pythonic way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Because the inner loop always end as the end of list, better is to Use `enumerate()` with `dict()` for this:

```
dictionary = dict(enumerate(ascii_uppercase))
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it doesn't answer the question as to why that's happening

Comment: @Chris added an explanation

Comment: I also didn't downvote, but why bother with a `dict` when sequences already have indexing?

Comment: @ekhumoro we do what OP wants to fix him/her for.

Comment: @ekhumoro why ask this to me, ask the OP for that? (S)He might be wanting it for any specific reason

Comment: @WasifHasan The idea is to help people write better code. It is redundant to use a mapping when sequences already have built-in indexing, so I think it's worth at least pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The second for-loop gets fully executed before the first one so it messes up the result. You can try this approach with just one for-loop instead:

```
dictionary = {i: ascii_uppercase[i] for i in range(len(ascii_uppercase))}
```

Comment: Wasif Hasan had a more elegant solution, I would stick with that one probably :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

dictionary = {key: value for key,value in enumerate(ascii_uppercase, 0)}
```

Output

```
{0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'F', 6: 'G', 7: 'H', 8: 'I', 9: 'J', 10: 'K', 11: 'L', 12: 'M', 13: 'N', 14: 'O', 15: 'P', 16: 'Q', 17: 'R', 18: 'S', 19: 'T', 20: 'U', 21: 'V', 22: 'W', 23: 'X', 24: 'Y', 25: 'Z'}
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are other suitable answers, I believe this is what you *think* you are doing.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase


{key: value for key,value in zip(range(0, len(ascii_uppercase)),ascii_uppercase)}
```